# pause and resume amanda backups?

Tags: wireless-networking, backup

Short and simple question -- is it possible to pause and later resume an amanda backup?

Longer backstory --

My laptop connects to my home network via wifi, and the `/home` directory is very large.  It sometimes takes up to 36 hours to run a full backup.  This clogs up my wifi pretty badly.

If I know the backup is coming, then I can prepare for it -- maybe move the laptop from wifi to wired, or maybe learn about bridging two different wifi adapters on two different wifi networks, or maybe just pause the backup for a few hours while I'm busy working.

But if it's already started, is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at breaking up the backup so that you aren't backing up everything at once.  Consider using exclude rules to exclude large objects like ISOs, videos, and possibly MP3s from the main backup.  These can be backed up in more or more alternate backups that select those files.

Examine your backup cycle.  Consider doing full backups less frequently, possibly with two or more levels of incremental backups.

Full backups may run faster if you run them over a hardwired link.

Alternatively, you may want to look at an backup based on the rsycn protocol.  I have had good experiences with BackupPC on both [Linux](https://www.systemajik.com/blog/setting-up-backuppc-on-ubuntu/) and [Windows](https://www.systemajik.com/blog/setting-up-backuppc-on-windows/).  The first backup takes a while, but subsequent backups, even full are much faster.

BackupPC is a disk based backup.  I still use Amanda for a subset of files I want backup media for.

Comment: A bunch of excellent solutions which I will investigate.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this command

`sudo -u amanda /usr/local/sbin/amadmin MyConfig due newlaptop /home`

which tells me roughly when I can expect the next full backup to occur.  I'm going to see if I can use that to pre-warn me about getting a wired connection in time.

But it would still be much nicer to pause a running backup if that option were available to me.